# How do I find duplicates in a sample using count and getting a boolean output

Tags: python

```
all_days=[]
for all_days in range(1,366):
    print(all_days)

import numpy as np
one_sample=np.random.choice(all_days,30,replace=False)

def repeat(one_sample):
    for all_days in one_sample:
        if one_sample.count(all_days):
            print(True)
        else:
            return False

print(repeat)
```

Comment: What is the objective of this code? What do u wanna do? Pls provide more details abt it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a minute to read [ask] for some tips to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Several thoughts:

- When specifying `replace=False` in *random.choices()*, you're already guaranteed that duplicates are eliminated.
- Replace the *print* in your function with *return*
- [*collections.Counter()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) can be used to efficiently count all elements so that you know how many times each element occurred.
- A simple and fast way to test for the presence of duplicates is `len(set(a)) == len(a)`.